# Using Sharepoint for Scrum

Tags: 2010, third-party-software

My company has recently decided to use Sharepoint more extensively. My group is beginning to adopt Agile methodologies. I'd like to merge these two initiatives as best I can. Specifically, I am looking for a good way to manage Scrum in SP. Has anyone found some useful tools in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to look into 21scrum, http://www.21scrum.com/.

Comment: +1 In addition to this, there is also a open source Scrum Template for SharePoint that helps Scrum teams to manage the backlog/stories/tasks in their sprint planning. http://scrum.codeplex.com/

Comment: @FalakMahmood: I had seen that codeplex Template, but it had gotten quite a few negative ratings recently, so I was quite hesitant. Have you any experience with it?

Comment: @kmote sorry I haven't tried myself so can't say anything about it, but heard from some friends that it needs a lot of improvement. Probably better try improving it rather than buying expensive 3rd party product.